# Compile typescript code in dockerfile does not work (Cannot find name 'process')

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV NODE_ENV=production

COPY package*.json .
    
RUN npm install && npm i -g typescript

COPY . .

RUN  tsc

CMD [ "node", "./dist/index.js" ]
```

And the following `package.json`:

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^12.5.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^14.14.37",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4"
  }
```

When I try to build the image, I get the following error:

```
Cannot find name 'process'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i --save-dev @types/node`
```

Does anyone know why that happens? I have `@types/node` installed.

Comment: seems like we need more info. you can add index.js/ts maybe?

Comment: @srknzl well the only thing thats from importance in `index.ts` is `const API_KEY = process.env.API_KEY;`. Otherwise, it's a standard discord bot.  Also a note - it compiles perfectly fine when using tsc on my system AND on an unrelated fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: `devDependencies` won't be installed for production mode

Comment: @ExplodingKitten thanks that was it. totally forgot about that. would you mind writing that as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`devDependencies` won't be installed for production mode.

So, you can:

- Move these packages to `dependencies` or
- Remove `NODE_ENV` environment variable or
- Use multi-stage build, where you will build TypeScript on the first stage (keep dependencies as is, but you don't need `production` here), and use JS files on the second stage (you don't need `devDependencies` here, so, `production` will work).